# How to check if FileTable is enabled in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, filetable

Before I store data into SQL Server `FileTable`, I need to know or verify that the `FileTable` exists in the database, then only I can add the records to `FileTable`.

If `FileTable` is not enabled or added to Database then I want to store the data in the BLOB. Anybody can help me with a stored proc which can tell me weather the `Filetable` exists in the database?

Comment: [This page](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/14/sql-server-working-with-filetables-in-sql-server-2012-part-1-setting-up-environment/) also shows how to check FileStream is enabled.

Comment: You should also check if an table exists by executing a SELECT query like this. `SELECT 1 FROM FileTable WHERE 0` note this works on MySQL.. this query returns 1 if the table exists.